# Why double reference value doesn't change when assigned to float variable in C++

Tags: c++, reference

I am trying to understand the concept of assigning a float to const reference double and the value of double doesn't change if the float value updated.

```
float d = 2.0;
const double & f = d;
d = 3.0;
std::cout << d << " " << f << std::endl;
```

output:

```
 3 2
```

What is the reason behind this.

However this issue is not seen when we set the reference variable as the same type as the other variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> However this issue is not seen when we set the reference variable as the same type as the other variable

That's the point; you can't bind reference to object with different type directly.

Given `const double & f = d;`, a temporary `double` will be constructed from `d`, then bound to the reference `f`. The modification on `d` has nothing to do with the temporary; they're two irrelevant objects. That's why you got different result when print out `d` and `f`.

BTW: Only the lvalue reference to const and rvalue reference could be bound to temporary, so `const double & f = d;` and `double && f = d;` work fine. Lvalue reference to non-const can't be bound to temporary, then `double & f = d;` won't work.